# IPython notebook: Passing variables from Python cell to Javascript cells

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am trying to pass some integers and some dictionaries from a python cell to a Javascript cell in Jupyter notebook. However, I googled a lot but still can not find a proper way to manage it... Could anyone help? Thanks!!

For example, I have the following dict in Python:

```py
data = {
      "a": 0,
      "b": 1
    }
```

How could I access data in a Javascript cell?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I make it work in a way not so nice:

First, define the dictionary in a javascript cell:

%%javascript

data = {};

Then pass the value in a Python cell:

data={ "a": 0, "b": 1 }

from IPython.display import Javascript

Javascript("data="+json.dumps(data))